# Which components update routing table?

Tags: arch-linux, routing

I am experiencing strange behavior on Arch Linux, when various virtual network interfaces lead to undesired automatic updates to the routing table. For example, when I start KVM.

Before (network is OK):

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
$ ip route get 173.194.222.99
173.194.222.99 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0  src 192.168.1.89
```

After (network is not OK):

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 vnet0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 vnet0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
$ ip route get 173.194.222.99
173.194.222.99 dev vnet0  src 169.254.195.255
```

The update happens with some delay. The `vnet0` route is not inserted, when I have a wired connection (its metric is 0).

I *think* this is not from [NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager).. Where else should one look for pointers, when debugging such issues?

Comment: I had `conmand` jumping virtual interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's `libvirtd` if that one is running.

Give us the output of `ps aux` so we can see what is running on your system.